# Add Static Block Above Content On Every Page

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I'd like to add a static block above the content on every page.

[image: Header]
[image: Header]

I've tried adding these to my local.xml but the block appears in the wrong place:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="cms/block" name="head_images ">
            <action method="setBlockId"><value>head_images</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

And

```
<default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="cms/block" name="head_images ">
            <action method="setBlockId"><value>head_images</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **Widget** for this.

Create a widget and set **Type** CMS Static Block under **frontend Properties**

In **Layout Updates** you can set

```
Display on: All Pages
Block Reference: Main content area
```

Under **widget option** tab select your static block.

Hope above will help!

Comment: Worked perfectly